# Terminology for plurality-agnostic objects

Tags: terminology

There's an interesting category of objects I've seen in jQuery and some other DOM tree traversal libraries.

A traditional way of mutating nodes in a tree would work in some way like this:

```
Elements matches = tree.findAll(condition);
for(Element e in matches) {
    if (condition2(e)) {
        e.setText("Hello");
    }
}
```

...or by using second-order functions:

```
tree.findAll(condition)
    .filter(condition2)
    .forEach(e -> e.setText("Hello"));
```

In those examples, there's an explicit distinction between the collection and the element. However, the type of object I'm talking about instead blurs the line by behaving both as if they're a collection and individal, mutatable elements.

```
tree.findAll(condition)
    .filter(condition2)
    .setText("Hello"); // Affects all matched nodes, if any
```

These objects essentially abstract away the concept of plurality. If the object is empty, all mutations are no-ops. If there are multiple elements, it automatically iterates through them and performs the appropriate operation on all of them. Operations that only make sense for individual elements, like `String s = matches.getText()` tend to, in some well-defined way, choose a specific element (such as the first one) to call.

My question is if there's some proper terminology to refer to these types of, for lack of a better term, "plurality-agnostic" objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are simply instances of the [Composite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) design pattern, which makes collections or structures of similar things behave as if they were a single thing.

Comment: This does indeed appear to the generalized form of what I'm talking about. Thank you.